# How can I take the textview text from custom listview contains 3 textviews and an imageview?

Tags: android

Considering the code below:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    TextView textView = (TextView) listView.findViewById(R.id.namee);
    String title = textView.getText().toString();
    TextView textVieww = (TextView) listView.findViewById(R.id.cityy);
    String city = textVieww.getText().toString();
    TextView textViewww = (TextView) listView.findViewById(R.id.placee);
    String place = textViewww.getText().toString();

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),title+" "+city+" "+place,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Data.title = title;
    Data.city = city;
    Data.place = place;

    final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame
                    , new ViewItemFrag()).commit();


}
```

How can I take access text of a `textView` which is inside a `listView` ?

Comment: What is your exact problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A row (entire view) in the `ListView` where user clicked is passed as a parameter called `view` to `onItemClick` function. Just use `view` instead of `listView` when retrieving your text, like so

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.namee);
...
```

Also please note that this isn't the best practice - prefer to this guide for an introduction to a [`Static Holder` pattern](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html).